# Por qué mi widget pasa al fondo al activar el efecto QDropShadowEffect en un Frame

Tags: pyqt5, pyqt

Buenas noches tengo el siguiente prblema.

En una interfaz de usuario planeo mostrar un grafico usando `pygal` y mostrarlo en un `frame` para poder agregar un effecto `QDropShadowEffect` en el Frame, sin embargo al agregar el efecto al frame contenedor por alguna razón el widget que se genera de Pygal pasa detras del frame.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta imagen pueden ver que al activar el effecto el widget generado por pygal se va detras, y solo **reaparece hasta que doy click en una zona fuera de la ventana** imagino que esto refresca la interfaz y por ello se vuelve a mostrar como debe.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta seguna iliutrsación se muestra como el grafico aparece sin problemas, pero el `QDropShadowEffect` no esta habilitado.

La pregunta es:

¿Como puedo mostrar el grafico generado en pygal dentro del frame y activar el effecto QDropShadowEffect en el frame contenedor?

Códigos:

Main.py

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QVBoxLayout,QGraphicsDropShadowEffect
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from nuevo import Ui_MainWindow
import pygal
from pygal.style import *

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QMainWindow,self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.show_pygal()

        #self.shadow_effect([self.ui.frame_pygal])

        
    def show_pygal(self):
        self.layout_v = QVBoxLayout()
        self.ui.frame_pygal.setLayout(self.layout_v)

        custom_style = Style(
            label_font_size=20,
            title_font_size=25,
            legend_font_size=20
        )

        bar = pygal.Line(style=custom_style)
        bar.add("New",[1,2,3,4,5])

        render = bar.render_data_uri()

        self.graphics_render = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(parent=self.ui.frame_pygal)
        self.graphics_render.setUrl(QUrl(render))

        self.layout_v.addWidget(self.graphics_render)
    
    def shadow_effect(self,widgets=[],blur=25,xofset=-2,yofset=-2):
        for w in widgets:
            self.effect = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(w)
            self.effect.setBlurRadius(blur)
            self.effect.setXOffset(xofset)
            self.effect.setYOffset(yofset)
            w.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect)



app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
app.exec_()
```

nuevo.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.stackedWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 0, 741, 511))
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.frame_pygal = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.page)
        self.frame_pygal.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 20, 381, 201))
        self.frame_pygal.setStyleSheet("background:white;\n"
"border-radius:50px;")
        self.frame_pygal.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_pygal.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_pygal.setObjectName("frame_pygal")
        self.frame_one = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.page)
        self.frame_one.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 300, 401, 211))
        self.frame_one.setStyleSheet("background:red;")
        self.frame_one.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_one.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_one.setObjectName("frame_one")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-40, 110, 631, 261))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("path/image.jpg"))
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label.raise_()
        self.frame_pygal.raise_()
        self.frame_one.raise_()
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
```